# In postgres how to query a string with ends with a single quote

Tags: sql, postgresql

We need a query to find out if there is any string value that ends with a single quote in a table in postgres

```
select * from cust where nam like '%'''
```

But this doesn't seem to work. We can insert into the table, but cannot query it like this.

Comment: Your query should do what you want.

Comment: The query you have will work as intended: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5f582/1/0

Comment: What does *seem to* mean? It works or it doesn't work?

Comment: Should work: `select 'test''' like '%'''; t`.  What is the data type for the field being queried? Also an example of the field values. Add as update to your question.

Comment: Might try: `select * from cust where trim(nam) like '%'''`

Comment: it works, ideally with `'%'''` you are escaping the character `'` unless you have spaces at the end of the names in which it would not end with `'` rather end with ` `.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work in DBeaver.

Comment: Given the number of issues that come up wrt to DBeaver on SO it should be regarded as broken in general. Run the query in `psql`(or any other client for that matter) and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL supports [C-Style Escapes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS), maybe this will make your example more readable:

```
SELECT E'Testme\'' LIKE E'%\'';
```

Returns true, tested with PostgreSQL 12.7 via psql and with DBeaver 21.0.0.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey I am not sure this answer really helps the issue at hand, perhaps it would be more appropriate to leave it as a comment